# How to set uploaded jpg type to be recognised as "image/jpg" instead of "application/octet-stream"

Tags: android, loopj, android-async-http

I am using Loopj's [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) This is my code:

```
File file = new File("sdcard/food.jpg");
params.put("image", file);
```

My problem is, php server received the images as `application/octet-stream` instead of `image/jpg`. I need it to be `image/jpg` as my server guy white-list uploaded files that have types of `image/jpg`, `image/png`, etc.

**UPDATE 1**

I've tried adding content type parameter to the application. However, php code still recognized it as `application/octet-stream`.

```
params.put("image", new FileInputStream(file), "image/jpg");
```

**UPDATE 2**

Since I need to move on with the project, what we do right now is propose server guy to implement mime sniffing by using exif. In php, we do it with [exif_imagetype()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php). All is well, so far. I will keep this question open until we find the solution that is implementable in android.

Comment: have you tried specifying file name instead of mime type? like `params.put("image", new FileInputStream(file), "food.jpg");`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: sorry I think it should be `params.put("image", new FileInputStream(file), "food.jpg", "image/jpg");` https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/RequestParams.java

Comment: or it can also be `params.put("image", new File("sdcard/food.jpg"), "image/jpg");` according to api doc

Comment: I also already did that :(

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same problem, yet I couldn't change application/octet-stream but I instead handle it on server:

```
    $info = getimagesize($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']);
    $type=$info['mime'];
```

here the type will be shown as image/jpg instead of application/octet-stream.